# Array detected empty in a function even if it has element in it

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue in my React code. I want to build an array of articles, with a delete button inside each one to delete the desired article.

But in pratice, my console.log from `deleteDailyStandItem()` always return an empty array. Have you an idea why ?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day :)

```
const deleteDailyStandItem = (index, id) => {
        console.log(dailyStandItemsDisplayed)
        //Delete the article from the DB thanks to the id

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getDailyStand()
        .then(dailyStandDB => {
            if(dailyStandDB){
                setDailyStand(dailyStandDB)
                getDailyStandDetails()
                .then(dailyStandItemsDB => {
                    for(let i = 0; i < dailyStandItemsDB.length; i++){
                        setDailyStandItemsDisplayed(dailyStandItemsDisplayed => [...dailyStandItemsDisplayed,
                        <article key={dailyStandItemsDB[i].id}>
                            <section>
                                <img src={config.dailystand_detail_pict_url + dailyStandItemsDB[i].pict_url} alt={"illustration"+dailyStandItemsDB[i].id}></img>
                            </section>
                            
                            <p>Description : {dailyStandItemsDB[i].description}</p>
                            
                            <Button onClick={() => {deleteDailyStandItem(i, dailyStandItemsDB[i].id)}}><DeleteIcon /></Button>
                        </article>])
                    }
                    
                })
            }
        })
    }, [])
```

Edit :

I did it like you said, and it works very well ! Thank you !

Comment: What is `dailyStandItemsDisplayed`. Please add related code and how you are declaring it in your code?

Comment: ```const [dailyStandItemsDisplayed, setDailyStandItemsDisplayed] = useState([])```

Comment: Then i've answered your question, add that to your code and see if it shows some data.

Comment: Yes it shows my datas without any problem. The issue is my deleteDailyStandItem() function doesn't recognize the dailyStandItemsDisplayed's datas

Comment: How you are calling `deleteDailyStandItem` and when?

Comment: deleteDailyStandItem() is called when the user click on the button :) That's only way to call it

Comment: What i meant was, when you click the button, are you sure everything has rendered and in place and sometime you need to wait for that. and is there a reason you are putting your button component in the state, can't you just put necessary data in state and then `map` it out in some `article` component?

Comment: It seems everything is not rendered, you're right. Honestly, I don't know to do it in another way :x

Comment: I've edited my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dailyStandItemsDisplayed` is a state variable you can add this to your code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(dailyStandItemsDisplayed)
}, [dailyStandItemsDisplayed])
```

You can change your code a little to do it another way:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getDailyStand()
        .then(dailyStandDB => {
            if(dailyStandDB){
                setDailyStand(dailyStandDB)
                getDailyStandDetails()
                .then(dailyStandItemsDB => {
                   //Check here if `dailyStandItemsDB` is a list/array 
                   setDailyStandItemsDisplayed(dailyStandItemsDB)
                    
                    
                })
            }
        })
    }, [])
```

and then:

```
return (
  <>
   {
     dailyStandItemsDisplayed.map((dailyStandItemsDB) => {
       return <article key={dailyStandItemsDB.id}>
         <section>
           <img src={config.dailystand_detail_pict_url + dailyStandItemsDB.pict_url} alt={"illustration"+dailyStandItemsDB.id}></img>
                            </section>
                            
          <p>Description : {dailyStandItemsDB.description}</p>
                            
          <Button onClick={() => {deleteDailyStandItem(i, dailyStandItemsDB.id)}}><DeleteIcon /></Button>
        </article>
     })
   }
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and tell you when it's done.

Comment: @Tholhen If it answers your question, please mark it as your answer. :)